# Is there any way that can limit different IPs in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, user-accounts

At first I want you to know that I am not a programmer right now and I have just started working on my own wordpress site. My website offers online courses and users have to pay a small amount of money to access their favorite course. The problem is that when a user registers, can share his account info and others can access the courses as well! Can we set some limitations that only one person can access the account?
I would be glad if you can help.

Comment: It is possible to restrict accessing by IP, but it's a bad solution, users might have different IPs in the many devices they might use, and static IPs are rare in the modern mobile world anyway.

Comment: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/two-factor-authentication/ something like this could help.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is install and activate Restricted Site Access plugin. After activating the plugin, go to Settings » Reading. Scroll down to the bottom and you will see options to configure restricted access.

[image]

https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-wordpress-site-access-by-ip-or-logged-in-users/

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. But I think it is just useful if we have different admins. It is not for users that want to buy account of my site!